# The end of [violation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

This tag is such a [violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/violation)

No excerpt. No wiki. 159 questions

In most languages there's a "violation" error message somewhere. The problem is that each message and language uses it differently. As such, it makes no sense to tie a PHP error about database violations to a memory access violation in Oracle.

In every question I reviewed the tag could be removed without any harm to the question, since the questions are related to their specific languages.

Comment: There is already [access-violation]. Usage guidance should probably point there.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BurnTheDiskpacks ?

Comment: Stats before featuring: Question +98/-1. No answers.

Comment: Then how can we ask about [tag:strict] [tag:aliasing] [tag:violation]? (Yes, they are all 3 existing tags...)

Comment: Looks like someone has jumped the gun already, only 100 questions with the tag now.  Either that are a lot of them got closed at some point.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Why should [tag:access-violation] be a tag? That sounds equally vague to me.

Comment: @jpmc26: an access violation is an exception. Some call it NullReferenceException. What's vague about that?

Comment: @ThomasWeller The tag wiki says it's a seg fault, so I think you just demonstrated my point. [tag:segmentation-fault] is clearer.

Comment: @jpmc26: yes, [segmentation-fault] seems to be the Linux term, [access-violation] the one for Windows. That's like [core-dump] and [crash-dump]. I like that separation, because I can answer [access-violation] and [crash-dump] but I can neither answer [segmentation-fault] nor [core-dump].

Comment: Stats at the end of burnination, Question at +168/-2. There's a clear approval for burnination.

Comment: There is also a [sharing-violation] tag (used... 4 times). Was about to replace [violation] in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822408/microsoft-interop-security-azroles-azauthorizationstoreclass-initialize-fails-wi)  by [sharing-violation], but I'm not sure now that I saw the weak added value of this. Better to simply remove tag ? or replace [access-violation]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/violation) has been *burninated*.

[image]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

---

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

The general rule is to tag the post with [access-violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-violation) where ever necessary.

## Progress:

The [violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/violation) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=violation),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bviolation%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bviolation%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bviolation%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bviolation%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/violation) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/violation) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/violation) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I think it makes sense to replace a tag on questions about violation of SQL constraints with [tag:constraints] tag

Comment: @Vadim Feel free to edit the answer! It's a community effort. :)

Comment: I'm not sure in my idea, seeking arguments for/against.

Comment: @BhargavRao No open questions remain in the tag now